# How to unzip - zip of zips and maintain the Same directory structure

Tags: apache-nifi

Can anyone please help me to advise what combination of nifi processors to take and how to loop through those processors for a Zip file that contains child zip files and still maintain the folder structure after unzipping them?

Basically, below is what I have:

ZIPPED File Structure

---

--CLASS.zip

```
    --CLASS1.zip

           --SUBJECT1.zip

           --SUBJECT2.zip

           --SUBJECT3.zip

           --SUBJECT4.zip



    --CLASS2.zip

           --SUBJECT1.zip

           --SUBJECT2.zip

           --SUBJECT3.zip

           --SUBJECT4.zip



    --CLASS3.zip

           --SUBJECT1.zip

           --SUBJECT2.zip

           --SUBJECT3.zip

           --SUBJECT4.zip
```

The level of zipping might go further but I gave just for illustration purpose. I want to maintain the same directory structure even after Unzipping like shown below:

### UNZIPPED Directory structure :

--CLASS

```
    --CLASS1

           --SUBJECT1

           --SUBJECT2

           --SUBJECT3

           --SUBJECT4



    --CLASS2

           --SUBJECT1

           --SUBJECT2

           --SUBJECT3

           --SUBJECT4



    --CLASS3

           --SUBJECT1

           --SUBJECT2

           --SUBJECT3

           --SUBJECT4
```

## Please suggest the best possible way to attain this.

Hi daggett,

[NiFi Flow image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c8cNk.png)

Did apply the NiFi flow as suggested by you, But its still not unzipping in the format as stated in my previous issue. Please advise.

Comment: `GetFile (recurse, zip) -> UnpackContent -> PutFile`

Comment: Hi daggett,

Many thanks for your reply. 

However, I did try your method but its unzipping only at the first level and also not maintaining the directory structure after unzipping. I will be editing my post with the screenshots for you to see. Please share your 2 cents on the same.

Many Thanks